# Is INTERSECT preferred over subquery?

Tags: mysql

I am working on question

> Find all students who do not appear in the Likes table (as a student who likes or is liked) and return their names and grades. Sort by grade, then by name within each grade.

I proposed doing the following, getting all people who don't have Likes and intersecting those with the people who don't like anyone:

```
SELECT name, grade
  FROM Highschooler h1
LEFT JOIN Likes l1
  ON (l1.ID1 = h1.ID)
WHERE l1.ID1 IS NULL
INTERSECT
SELECT name, grade
  FROM Highschooler h1
LEFT JOIN Likes l1
  ON (l1.ID2 = h1.ID)
WHERE l1.ID2 IS NULL
ORDER BY grade, name
```

An alternative way to do this is with a subquery (as I found online)

```
select name, grade from Highschooler H1
where H1.ID not in (select ID1 from Likes union select ID2 from Likes) 
order by grade, name;
```

Which way is preferred? I think my method is more readable.

Comment: I'd say both are acceptable. The difference could be in performances and that aspect usually depends on the given application.

Comment: I thought MySQL doesn't support intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Adrien said, both are acceptable ways of doing it,
I think your way is more readable because of the capitalized functions and better indentation and not because of the query itself.

This is how i would do it for example:

```
SELECT name, grade
FROM Highschooler H1
LEFT JOIN Likes AS L1 ON L1.ID1 = H1.ID OR L1.ID2 = H1.ID
WHERE L1.ID1 IS NULL
ORDER BY grade, name
```

This case would be called an Anti-Join. Read more about those here

https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Here is another nice blog post about the different kind of joins with some diagrams to accompany them:
http://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/06/you-probably-dont-use-sql-intersect-or-except-often-enough/

our case would be[image: Left Anti Join]

Comment: This is an antijoin?

Comment: yes, you're joining a table but you actually want all the values from the first table that don't match anything. only in your case we're matching on 2 values instead of 1

Comment: @Phil added another link, it has some nice Venn diagrams including our case

Comment: You are a very amazing person!

Comment: :) thank you, glad to be of help. don't forget to accept an answer to mark the question as solved, but only if you feel like your question was fully answered. If you have some more questions i'd be glad to help, feel free to tag my name in a comment under any future questions you may have

Answer (score 0):

No, your query is not very readable. Read it in plain English: 1. Make a large list of all pupils and their likes. 2. If no likes record is found for a pupil, keep the pupil record nontheless. 3. Then remove all records that do contain likes (thus only keeping those pupils who don't have likes). 4.-6. Do the same with the other person in the likes table. 7. Intersect the two result sets.

The original task was only: Find pupils that don't exist in the likes table.

```
select name, grade
from highschooler
where not exists
(
  select *
  from likes
  where likes.id1 = highschooler.id
     or likes.id2 = highschooler.id
)
order by grade, name;
```

Keep your queries as simple as possible. SQL is made to read more or less like you would word the task in English. It's not always possible to formulate a task in such simple form, but you can always try :-)

The anti-join pattern you are using in your intersect query is a trick to overcome weaknesses in young DBMS that don't deal well with IN and EXISTS yet. You should use tricks only when necessary, not when dealing with such a simple task as the one given.